# How do I directly create an NSDictionary that can be used by NSSpeechSynthesizer.addSpeechDictionary?

Tags: swift, macos, nsspeechsynthesizer

My goal is to add a custom dictionary to an `NSSpeechSynthesizer` so that I can create custom pronunciations of words.

When I pass it a dictionary that appears correct to me, of type `[String, AnyObject]` to `addSpeechDictionary` it fails with a `-50` error.  I have tried an array of methods to build the dictionary and none of them seem to
satisfy the requirements.

The latest was the below.  When I get it to compile like this code, I get a generic `-50` error, which appears to be a swift IO error.

```swift
import AppKit

let speaker = NSSpeechSynthesizer()
let speechRawDictionary: NSDictionary = [ "fish": "fiiiiiiiiiiish"]
if let srd = speechRawDictionary as? [String: AnyObject] {
    debugPrint(srd)
    let speechDictionary = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: srd.map{(key: NSSpeechSynthesizer.DictionaryKey(rawValue: $0.key), value: $0.value)})
    speaker.addSpeechDictionary(speechDictionary)
}

speaker.startSpeaking("I enjoy fish")
```

which returns

```
2023-03-14 11:31:57.868 swift-frontend[96609:1806502] NSSpeechSynthesizer: [NSSpeechSynthesizer addSpeechDictionary:] - Error -50
```

This code was mostly a copy of a bit I found in https://github.com/ooper-shlab/MySpeechSynthesis-Swift/blob/master/MySpeechSynthesis/SpeakingTextWindow.swift (specifically around https://github.com/ooper-shlab/MySpeechSynthesis-Swift/blob/master/MySpeechSynthesis/SpeakingTextWindow.swift#L641).

Again, my goal is simply to add a dictionary so I can do custom pronunciations of words and phrases.  For example, to pronounce "emacspeak" as "e mac speak".

Platform: MacOS 13.2.1 (22D68)
Swift:
driver version: 1.62.15 Apple Swift version 5.7.2 (swiftlang-5.7.2.135.5 clang-1400.0.29.51)
Target: arm64-apple-macosx13.0

Comment: I spent some time on this. Even passing in a seemingly correct dictionary to `addSpeechDictionary` results in a -50 error (which seems to mean *"paramErr: error in user parameter list"*). I couldn't find a single example of using `NSSpeechSynthesizer addSpeechDictionary` anywhere on the Internet.

Comment: Might be useful: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsspeechsynthesizer/dictionarykey/1448534-pronunciations

Comment: @MrDeveloper Even when using the proper dictionary, based on that documentation, the call to `addSpeechDictionary` still results in a runtime error message and no change in any pronunciation.

Comment: @HangarRash Unfortunately, it seems that this error keeps happening - when running in a Playground, I encounter no error but the pronunciation is not considered.